# Jest fails unless use --no-cache, even with babel-jest and .babelrc

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

This test passes if run Jest with `--no-cache`, but as per error msg below, I shouldn't get error with `babel-jest`, which I have.

See my .babelrc and package.json below, and test files.

**ERROR:**

```
Using Jest CLI v12.1.1, jasmine2, babel-jest
 FAIL  __tests__/junk-test.js
Runtime Error
  - SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word in file 'junk.js'.

    Make sure your preprocessor is set up correctly and ensure your 'preprocessorIgnorePatterns' configuration is correct: http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#preprocessorignorepatterns-array-string
    If you are currently setting up Jest or modifying your preprocessor, try `jest --no-cache`.
    Preprocessor: node_modules/babel-jest/src/index.js.
    Make sure your '.babelrc' is set up correctly, for example it should include the 'es2015' preset.
    Jest tried to the execute the following preprocessed code:
    var junk = function () {
        return "thing";};

    export { junk };
```

**__tests__/junk-test.js**

```
// __tests__/junk-test.js

jest.unmock('../junk.js');

import {junk} from '../junk';


describe('JUNK AwesomeProject', () => {
  it('Junk var = string', () => {
    var retVal = junk();
    expect(retVal).toEqual("thing");
  });
});
```

**junk.js**

```
var junk = function(){
    return "thing";
}

export {junk};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babelify": "7.3.0",
    "react": "15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "15.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "12.1.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "*",
    "jest-cli": "12.1.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils/"
    ]
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

### **UPDATE**

Ahh. Changing junk.js to an explicit return and now the test passes.

What's odd is Flow didn't catch this, maybe ESlint would, that's next on my list to try:

```
var junk = function() { 
   var stuff = "thing"; 
   return stuff; 
}
```

Comment: btw: that error msg is not too helpful, it should state the offending word in the error: `Unexpected reserved word in file`.

Comment: ESlint didn't catch this as odd, with some basic default settings.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't to do with the way you're using export { junk };? what happens if you just do export default junk? Or use export const junk = () =>?

Comment: I can't reproduce the original error. I didn't make any changes to Jest config, except adding `"preprocessorIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/build/"
    ],` and installing `babel-eslint`.